# Angular 4 call couchdb has CORS error, but no preflight shows up in fiddler

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, cors, couchdb, preflight

I have an application written in Angular 4 calling a couchdb all on localhost but different ports.

I have been using couchdb with an Aurelia app without any issue.

Now that I am switching to Angular 4 and Angular MD I can seem to get pass this cors problems.

Here is the code that calls Couchdb

> private commonUpdate(content: any, url: string, method: string =
>   'put') {
>
> ```
> console.log("in common")
> const myHeaders = new Headers();
> myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
>
> const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, withCredentials: true });
>
> if (content && content._rev && content._rev.length >= 5) {
>   url = url + '/' + content._id;
> }
>
> const status = new DbStatus();
> status.ok = false;
>
> let response: any;
> try {
>   if (content) {
>     const contentJson: string = JSON.stringify(content);
>     this.http.post(url, contentJson, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
>       console.log(data['results']);
>     })
>   } 
>
>   status.ok = this.isHttpStatusSuccess(response.status);
>   if (status.doc) {
>     if (Array.isArray(status.doc.docs)) {
>       if (status.doc.docs.length === 0) {
>         status.ok = false;
>         status.reason = 'Empty Array';
>         if (!status.error) status.error = status.reason;
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   status.httpStatus = response.status;
>   status.response = response;
> } catch (error) {
>   status.ok = false;
> }
> ```

Error message:

VM27427:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5984/_session. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

```
[cors] 
origins = *
credentials = true
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer
Couch-Rev, Set-Cookie
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
```

I don't understand why this does work.
Again fiddler doesn't show a preflight OPTION method request.

However running the OPTION method from postman returns allowed methods of GET and HEAD.  Maybe the browser is caching it, but I have dev tools open with caching disable setting checked.

Suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> VM27427:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5984/_session. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

That sounds like the problem is just that the URL you’re giving to the `this.http.post` call in your code has no protocol part—that is, you’re only giving `localhost:5984/_session` to the call but you should be giving it `http://localhost:5984/_session`. You need to just add the `http://`.

So as far as why you’re not seeing an `OPTIONS` request, I guess that’s only because the browser is stopping before ever trying the `OPTIONS`—because without a protocol part in the URL, the browser can’t even determine if the URL you’ve given is cross-origin or not.